# What happens when Elasticsearch is restarted with Magento 2.3.x

Tags: magento2.3, search, elasticsearch

May seem like a simple question, but what are all of the impacts when **ElasticSearch** is restarted in a running Magento 2.3.x store?

Do indexes need to be reindexed?

Any other items that have to be run/redone?

Answer (score 1):

The impact will be during that period of time(When ES is down) it may happen that **Catalog Search results** and **Category Pages** may not be accessible.

When Elasticsearch down then **catalog_search** index should be disabled for some time or switch to another search engine (i.e. MySQL).

For other items, it depends on a few other things as well

> - Elasticsearch clause parameter re-configuration
> - If Magento having any third party module especially for Elasticsearch then it may require Indexing
> - Why Elasticsearch restarted (It was for version upgrade/downgrade )
> - Any OS upgrade was triggered

For a safe side, we should reindex once Elastic Search is restarted

```
 php bin/magento indexer:reindex  catalogsearch_fulltext
```

Comment: With a restart of ES, aren't the indices saved in files and reloaded? So once ES restarts fully, all searches and category paths should be restored without needing a reindex?

Comment: @Rob on ES restarting, magento reindex is recommended.